# What does a record in the sys.dm_exec_requests with corresponding blocking session id is not showing in the same result set mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

sys.dm_exec_requests - these are the active requests

sys.dm_exec_sessions - these are the active sessions

A session can have 1 or more requests.

From perspective of detecting and resolving blocking, I am exploring the above dmvs. I am observing that session_id that exist in sys.dm_exe_sessions doesn't exist in sys.dm_exec_requests.

For example - In the sys.db_exec_requests there is a record with Wait type as `LCK_M_X`, and wait resource as `KEY: 2......`. The corresponding blocking session id is not showing in sys.dm_exec_requests.

It shows in the sys.dm_exec_sessions with status as `sleeping`. What does this scenario mean - that is - request blocked due to a sleeping session?

Comment: This is not a duplicate because it asks `What does a record in the sys.dm_exec_requests with corresponding blocking session id is not showing in the same result set mean?` where as the one marked as the duplicate is how to identify the blocking session's query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server's connection model, there are three concepts: a connection, a session and a request.

The session represents the logical state of the relationship between client and server, whereas the connection represents the actual physical network connection.

A client can make multiple physical connections, and can have multiple sessions. Normally these have one-to-one correspondence, except for system sessions which have no underlying connection. (Theoretically it's possible to have multiple client connections connected to a single session also, but this is unusual).

---

A session can then make one or more requests, these are in `sys.dm_exec_requests` and have a many-to-one relationship with `sys.dm_exec_sessions`.

In cases when [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-ver16) is used, it is possible for there to be multiple active requests per session, this is why it is a one-to-many relationship.

A session doesn't have to have an active request. `blocking_session_id` just shows the session that is blocking, which may have made a request previously which locked the data, but has not committed it and is not currently running any request. A request must have a session, but a session does not need to have a request.

Comment: Does a request always have corresponding session?

Comment: Yes, it does, the column is not nullable

Comment: Could you specifically include the answer for the question - `What does a record in the sys.dm_exec_requests with corresponding blocking session id is not showing in the same result set mean?`

Comment: A session doesn't have to have an active request. `blocking_session_id` just shows the session that is blocking, which may have made a request previously which locked the data, but has not committed it and is not currently running any request. As I said, a request must have a session, but a session does not need to have a requets.

Comment: Since it hasn't committed it, then shouldn't the request be showing as active request. Aren't requests within transaction considered some kind of request?

Comment: No, a request is a currently running command. The fact the session is still just holding locks does not make it a request by itself.

Answer (score 2):

[sys.dm_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - "*Returns information about each request that is executing in SQL Server.*"

Essentially this is a view of every executing query and database command. The `session_id` in here should relate to a session in `sys.dm_exec_sessions`. In a sense, this is a child view to `sys.dm_exec_sessions`.

[sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - "*Returns one row per authenticated session on SQL Server. `sys.dm_exec_sessions` is a server-scope view that shows information about all active user connections and internal tasks.*"

This is essentially a view of every connection to the SQL Server instance. If someone connects to the server but isn't actively running any queries, then you won't see their `session_id` from this view in the `sys.dm_exec_requests` view. This is a parent view to `sys.dm_exec_requests`, in a sense.

Comment: Could you specifically include the answer for the question - `What does a record in the sys.dm_exec_requests with corresponding blocking session id is not showing in the same result set mean?`